# C++11 auto variable : float array vs auto

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Size of float array declared is suing auto is different than actual size. why is it so ??

For e.g:

declaration:

```
float duto[] = {2.2222f,2.223f,34.5f,1.0f,9.0f};
auto dutot = {2.2222f,2.223f,34.5f,1.0f,9.0f};
```

Size print:

```
std::cout << " float array size v: " << sizeof(duto)<<std::endl;
std::cout << " auto v: " << sizeof(dutot)<<std::endl;
```

Output:

```
float array size v: 20
auto v: 16
```

Comment: the type of auto here is actually initializer_list<float>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`auto dutot = {2.2222f,2.223f,34.5f,1.0f,9.0f};`

`auto` here is actually deduced as `initializer_list<float>`. so you are printing the size of `initializer_list<float>`.

I just took a look at `initializer_list` implementation in g++ 4.8.2 on my ubuntu 14.04. it contains two members `_M_array` and `_M_len`. `_M_array` is a pointer, `_M_len`'s type is size_t. So I guess your machine is 64bit. since pointer and size_t are usually 8 bytes on 64bit platform.

Comment: But please write it down a little cleaner if possible (one sentence per line, for example). BTW, I think that `size_t` is 4 bytes either case, so perhaps the additional 4 bytes are structure padding for 64-bit platforms.

Comment: @barakmanos, I printed sizeof(size_t) on my 64bit machine, it's 8 bytes.

Comment: So it's a good thing I said "I think" :) ... It makes sense, now that I think about it. On a 64-bit machine, you can theoretically have a statically-allocated array or structure, larger than 4 GB (2^32 bytes), so `size_t` must be platform-dependent (4 bytes on 32-bit platforms, and 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms).

Comment: @barakmanos, `size_t` is a typedef which you might think of as an `ptrdiff_t` counterpart for indicies. And I'd say it is guaranteed to be of the target platform pointer size all the time.

Comment: @ixSci or larger. It is just guaranteed to be able to store the largest address possible.